# Clear module import cache after executing Python code from zip file

Tags: python, module, zip, python-import

I'm looking for a way to reliably clear the module import cache after loading and executing code from zip files (the zip files with Python code serve as a "plugin").

The current way I'm using causes stale code to be executed, meaning code from previously imported zip files is executed. I'm looking for advice because the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.invalidate_caches) (3.11) don't seem to sufficiently handle this case, at least not for me with the case of package imports from within the zip file (the package is also part of the zip file).

This is the code that loads the zip file:

```
import importlib
from zipimport import zipimporter

# Load main.py:start_func()
# allow package imports in `main.py`
sys.path.insert(0, zippath)
importer = zipimporter(zippath)
main = importer.load_module('main')

# execute `start_func` function in main.py
main.start_func()

# Cleanup
for name, mod in list(sys.modules.items()):
    if not hasattr(mod, '__file__') or not mod.__file__:
        continue
    if mod.__file__.startswith(zippath):
        del sys.modules[name]

if zippath in sys.path:
    sys.path.remove(zippath)
importlib.invalidate_caches()
```

The zip file has this structure and content

```
/
+-- main.py
|   from util import bar
|
|   def start_func():
|       bar()
|       ...
|
+-- /foo
     +-- __init__.py
     |
     +-- util.py
         
         def bar():
             print('hello')
```

The problem is that when I have multiple zip files with different functions in `util.py`, subsequent imports *can* mix up the `util.py` and use one that was imported previously imported from another zip file (presumably because it was cached as part of the import during the execution/import of `start_func` from the zip file).

Are there any avenues that I can explore? For instance, is there a way to check the module cache to inspect where code would be executed from (which module - where it's located)? Should this way of importing and executing the zip files work in principle or is there anything else that needs to be done to cleanup after the execution of the zip function?

Any help is appreciated.